# NSComboBox vertical alignment

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, vertical-alignment, nscombobox

i have an `NSComboBox` that displays text not vertically aligned.
Is there a method to vertical align text inside an `NSComboBox`?

[image]

As you can see, it's very strange and it doesn't change on fontsize basis. I've searched [`NSComboBox` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSComboBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but the only resource available is for the popup displayed items (like `intercellSpacing` or `setItemHeight:`).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I realise this is 8 years ago so probably well in the back of your mind but did you ever crack this please? I'm having a similar issue!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
NSComboBox* cbx = ZGKeyComboBox.new;
// NSViewMaxYMargin means: The top margin between the receiver and its superview is flexible.
cbx.autoresizingMask = NSViewMaxYMargin;
cbx.itemHeight = cbx.itemHeight + 3; // addSubview will center vertically
NSRect r = NSMakeRect(x, y, width, cbx.itemHeight + 5);
cbx.frame = r;
...
[parent addSubview: cbx];
```